# Redux state doesn't log the properties of the state object

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

So I'm updating my redux's state, and when I console.log(props.client) in the component that I am using it , it works fine and shows the 2 properties that are stored inside this object state. But when I try to console.log(props.client.email), it it says that it's undefined which is so confusing to me .

> ```
> console.log(props.client);
> console.log(props.client.email);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is probably rendering multiple times and one of the times it renders the client isn't set so you get an error. You can access possibly unset sub properties with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), in your case:

```
console.log(props?.client);
console.log(props?.client?.email);
```

I would advise you have a look at the redux devtools and see what the initial state is, what actions are dispatched and what changes they made to the state as that is far more productive in identifying what is wrong with application as posting a "it doesn't work" question on stack overflow.